# Xamarin.Forms: Reload a contentpage contained in a tabbedpage to update the data

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

The default language of my Xamarin.Forms app  for Android is French. I would like the user to be able to change the language and choose English or Spanish. To do this, I added 3 resource files: AppResources.resx, AppResources.en.resx, and AppResources.es.resx to a Resx folder.  In these files, I filled in the keywords to be translated.
Here is the beginning of the xaml code  of the page to be translated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:syncfusion="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.ListView.XForms;assembly=Syncfusion.SfListView.XForms"
         xmlns:sync="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.XForms.Buttons;assembly=Syncfusion.Buttons.XForms"
         xmlns:resx="clr-namespace:MemoCourses.Resx"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         x:Class="MemoCourses.Views.ParametreDestPage"
         Title="{x:Static resx:AppResources.ParamDest_Titre}">
```

And the corresponding cs code  :

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using MemoCourses.Models;
using MemoCourses.ViewModels;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;
using MemoCourses.Resx;

namespace MemoCourses.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class ParametreDestPage : ContentPage
    {
        ObservableCollection<Parametre> DB_ParametreList = new ObservableCollection<Parametre>();
        ReadAllParametreList dbparametre = new ReadAllParametreList();
        ObservableCollection<Panier> DB_PanierList = new ObservableCollection<Panier>();
        ReadAllPanierList dbpanier = new ReadAllPanierList();
        //
        Parametre parametres;
        // ===

        public ParametreDestPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string language = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name;
            picker.SelectedIndex = language == "es" ? 2 : language == "en" ? 1 : 0;
        }
    
        // ...
    
        private void picker_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (App.SelectedIndex == picker.SelectedIndex)
                return;
            App.SelectedIndex = picker.SelectedIndex;
            CultureInfo language = new CultureInfo(picker.SelectedIndex == 0 ? "" : picker.SelectedIndex == 1 ? "en" : "es");
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = language;
            AppResources.Culture = language;
            Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new ParametreDestPage());
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works except that this contentpage is part of a tabbedpage, and when I reload the page with the code:

```
Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new ParametreDestPage());
```

... the title bar and tabs are no longer displayed.  The user can no longer go back or access the menu.
To complete the information in my code, here is the xaml page  of the tabbedpage:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MemoCourses.Views"  
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        BarBackgroundColor="DarkOliveGreen"
        BarTextColor="White"
        SelectedTabColor="White"
        Title="{x:Static resx:AppResources.ParamPage_Titre}"
        x:Class="MemoCourses.Views.ParametrePage">
<local:ParametreDestPage />
<local:ParametreVersionsPage />

</TabbedPage>
```

How do I apply the changes (refresh the data) to the ParametreDestPage by leaving the title and tabs visible?
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: `myTabbedPage.Children[x] = new NavigationPage(ParametreDestPage());`.  Or, you could re-use the existing `NavigationPage` and just replace the content page.  Or, you could try just putting all of the page's initialization into a method that you could re-run when the language changes.

Comment: Excuse me, can you detail a little more the 3 solutions because I wrote this code ParametrePage.Children[0] = new NavigationPage(new ParametreDestPage()) but it returns the error CS0120.  I do not understand the other solutions. Thank you!

Comment: you need the current **instance** of `ParametrePage`.  If you do not already have a reference to it, you can use `(ParametrePage)App.Current.MainPage` to get it